# SQL - Transpose one column of data into a row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I am looking to take the values of a single column and transpose them into the corresponding row for each ClientGUID. A simple example of the of what I have post SELECT statement is:

| ClientGUID | DxCode |
| --- | --- |
| 12345 | 50.8 |
| 12345 | 62.5 |
| 12345 | 42.1 |

What I am trying to accomplish is this, if possible:

| ClientGUID | DxCode1 | DxCode2 | DxCode3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 50.8 | 62.5 | 42.1 |

For this example my SELECT statement looks a such:

```
    SELECT ClientGUID, DxCode
    FROM MyTable
    WHERE ClientGUID = 12345
```

Any thoughts or direction would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: What if a different ClientGUID has only 2 rows? And another one has 7?

Comment: Good question.  For the sake of the example I really simplified it.  I reality, the number of rows for each ClientGUID will indeed vary.  My plan was to have a set number of columns set to the maximum possible rows or DxCode values for any ClientGUID.  For example each ClientGUID could have up to 10 DxCodes.  So I was hoping to have columns DxCode1 thru DxCode10, then pass a NULL value if there is no corresponding DxCode.  Does that make sense?

Comment: (Please always tag with the minimum version of SQL Server you need to support; as you see, solutions can vary.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` for this, e.g.:

```
;WITH src AS
(
  SELECT ClientGUID, DxCode,
    rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ClientGUID ORDER BY @@SPID)
  FROM dbo.ClientDxCodes
  -- WHERE ClientGUID = 12345
)
SELECT ClientGUID, DxCode1 = [1], DxCode2  = [2], DxCode3 = [3],
    DxCode4 = [4], DxCode5 = [5], DxCode6  = [6], DxCode7 = [7],
    DxCode8 = [8], DxCode9 = [9], DxCode10 = [10]
FROM src
PIVOT 
(
  MAX(DxCode) 
  FOR rn IN ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10])
) AS p;
```

Output:

| ClientGUID | DxCode1 | DxCode2 | DxCode3 | DxCode4 | DxCode5 | DxCode6 | DxCode7 | DxCode8 | DxCode9 | DxCode10 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 50.8 | 62.5 | 42.1 | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* | *null* |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=315064518ba4c2d257794ce2e8fe8e3f)

Answer (score 2):

In this type of query the number of values may vary and it is generally simpler and more flexible to use `STRING_AGG()` to list all the values.
We can choose the seperator used between the values. One option which can be interesting is to use a newline and present the values as a vertical list.

> ```
> SELECT
>   ClientGUID,
>   STRING_AGG(DxCode, ', ') DxCodes
> FROM myTable
> GROUP BY ClientGUID
> ORDER BY ClientGUID;
> ```
>
> ```
> ClientGUID | DxCodes            
> ---------: | :------------------
>      12345 | 50.80, 62.50, 42.10
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=4fc9485385f506e82174328c32eb327f)*

Comment: My apologies.  This is a great answer but I forgot to mention I am using SQL Server 2016 unfortunately.  Sorry about that.